# Find the number of sets of cardinality $m$ that are subsets of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ such that the sum of the elements of the subset is divisible by $k$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinations

For specific cases with small numbers, this works out fairly easily using straightforward enumeration and modular arithmetic. However, my question is: how do we solve this problem in general?

Comment: If you are happy with a reasonable approximation, it's probably close to ${n \choose m} / k$. And to clarify, should the $m$ numbers be distinct?

Comment: @TMM The sets are requested to have cardinality $m$ so must have $m$ distinct elements.

Comment: @drhab That is what I assumed, but the problem becomes a lot easier if they are not necessarily distinct. (And $\{1,1\}$ could also be viewed as a multiset of cardinality $2$.)

Comment: I did some computations for small $m$ and $k$, looked for the results in [OEIS](http://oeis.org) and found: $m=2$, $k=3$ is A007997; $m=2$, $k=4$ is A001971; $m=3$, $k=4$ is A032801; $m=3$, $k=5$ is A0011912.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of $m$-element subsets of $\{1 \ldots n\}$ where the sum of the elements in the subset *equals* $k$ with the generating function $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n(1+xy^i)$, examining the coefficient of $x^my^k$. To get the number of subsets whose sum is *divisible by* $k$, you could simply add up the coefficients of $x^my^K$ for all multiples $K$ of $k$. However, it is probably more computationally efficient to expand the generating function product in the polynomial quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/\left<y^k-1\right>$; then the number you are looking for is the coefficient of $x^m$.

I don't know if Mathematica lets you calculate this way, but Magma does. You can test it at [the Magma online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/), with the following sample code:

`m:=2;
k:=3;
Z<x,y>:=PolynomialRing(Integers(),2);
X:=quo<Z|y^k-1>;
for n in {1..20} do
  z:=&*[X!(1+x*y^i):i in {1..n}];
  n,Coefficient(Coefficient(z,1,m),2,0);
end for;`

This code checks against the results in Julián Aguirre's comment above.